# How can I get this overlay function to work in my HTML e-commerce project?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, function

It's an e-commerce project (incomplete) that uses PHP, a PHPMYADMIN Database called ecommerce with a table called products, HTML, and Javascript. I have a "css" and "images" folder I use for resources.

Code summarized:
I load data from the products table to print out in html format (I used recursion and echo in php to do this.) There is an onclick tag for each item printed that calls the "openNav()" function. The openNav() function takes one parameter which remembers the product number. openNav() is supposed to display an overlay with more information on the product.

The problem:
The overlay never appears.

Code:

## **Products.php**

```
\<!DOCTYPE HTML\>
\<html\>
\<head\>
\<link href="css/Products.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /\>
\</head\>

\<body\>

    <!-- The overlay -->
    <div id="prodOverlay" class="overlay">
    
        <!-- Button to exit the overlay -->
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeProdOverlay()">&times;</a>
    
        <!-- Product Overlay Contents -->
        <div class="overlay-content">
            <label id = "disItemNum">couldnt find number</label>
            <label id = "disInfo">error in loading description</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        //opens the product menu (presently does absolutely nothing because it doesnt appear)
        function openNav(itemNum){
            document.getElementById("prodOverlay").style.height = "100%";
            document.getElementById("disItemNum").innerHTML = itemNum;
        }
        //closes the product menu
        function closeProdOverlay() {
            document.getElementById("prodOverlay").style.width = "0%";
        }
    </script>
    
    <?php
        //sever login information
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "ecommerce";
    
        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
    
        //retrieves data from sql
        $sql = "SELECT 'item number', title, description, picture, price FROM products";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    
        //iterates through products and prints to screen
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $ind = 1; //records number of iterations
            // output data of each row
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo 
                    "<div onclick=\"openNav(" . strval($ind) . ")\" style=\"cursor:pointer\" class = \"item\"> <img src=\"images/". $row["picture"] . /* product info in list also assigns each product an id for js */
                    "\" alt=\"product\" title=\"product\">" . $row["price"]  . 
                    "  " . $row["title"]. " " . strval($ind) . "</div><br>";
                $ind++;
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
    ?>

\</body\>
\</html\>
```

## ***Products.css***

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(101, 107, 155);
}
.overlay {
    height: 0%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed; 
    z-index: 1; 
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9); 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    transition: 0.5s; 
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%; 
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
    margin-top: 30px; 
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 25px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.item img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 -25px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {

    .overlay .closebtn {
        font-size: 40px;
        top: 15px;
        right: 35px;
    }
}
```

## **[Table Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WIQU.png)**

- I've tried getting rid of the parameter in the openNav() method.
- I've tried changing the parameter in the openNav() method.
- I also tried invoking the method in the browser using developer tools but it still hasn't worked for me.
- I tried playing around with the css code as well but I have not had any luck there either.

---

I used code from here to make the overlay:
[www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_curtain_menu.asp)

Comment: Your overlay has width:0;... check your browser console if you have some errors

Comment: yep, that was it. I went in the browser and set the values to 100% for height and width and noticed it was the issue. I changed the function to open up the right way